# Maximum and minimum of a composition

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

I have :
$$f(x)=g(3x^2)+xg(x)$$

I know:$$$$
 $f(0)$ is a critical point, $g(0)=0$, $$$$
$g'(x)\ne0$, $\exists g''(x)$

I also know $g$ function is a strictly decreasing function. How can I determinate if the critical point in $x=0$ is a maximum or a minimum?

Comment: if f is a strictly decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}$ it cannot have a maximom nor a minimum

Comment: @miracle173 Sorry, it's $g$ not $f$, just edited

Comment: hint: Express g by its taylor polynom, so $g(x)=ax+r(x)$, $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{r(x)}{x}=0$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=g(3x^2)+xg(x)$$

$$f'(x)=6xg'(3x^2)+g(x)+xg'(x)$$

$$f''(x)=6g'(3x^2)+36x^2g''(3x^2)+g'(x)+g'(x)+xg''(x)$$

$$f''(0)=8g'(0) \lt 0$$